# Accessing Map View in another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, maps

I'm working on a map based application where I'm using a side menu for control of the map (i.e. changing map type, etc). I'm using this library to implement the slide menu: https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu. I'm wondering what the best way to control the map in one view controller from a different view controller?

The App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
    UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];

    [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];
    [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];

    return YES;
}
```

I then have this Action linked to a button on the primary view controller which shows reveals the side bar like so:

```
- (IBAction)leftReveal:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:nil];
}
```

Heres a video that demonstrates the functionality of the side bar that I'm trying to emulate: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbfu13fkWZ4

Comment: Use Composition design pattern, the technique of creating objects that have references to other objects and allows them to work together.

Comment: Are you using the UISplitViewController?  Or something like facebook's custom slide out?
EDIT: Whoops, just saw the MFSideMenuContainerViewController